# Handling exceptions in Spring URL security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I am using SPRING URL security to secure my url resources.

1. This is configured in my deployment descriptor (web.xml) as follows:

   ```
    <filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
   ```
2. Configuration in SPRING SECURITY XML configuration file.

   ```
   <http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" disable-url-rewriting="true" access-decision-manager-ref="urlSecurityAccessDecisionManager" > 
   <access-denied-handler ref="accessDeniedHandler" /> <!--if access is denied (false) I'll be redirected to some JSP-->      

   <intercept-url pattern="/getGroupMembers.action*" access="isAuthenticated() and    
       (request.getParameter('groupId')!= null ?
         amIAMemberOfThisGroup(request.getParameter('groupId')) : true)"/>
   ```
3. The implementation of amIAMemberOfThisGroup(int groupId) is as follows:

   ```
    public boolean amIAMemberOfThisGroup(int groupId) throws Exception {
         Group group = getEntityManager().find(Group.class, groupId);
         if (group == null) {
             throw new Exception("Group not found. Invalid Group Id:" + groupId + .");
         }
     //if logged in user is member of this group return true else false        
     }
   ```
4. This is working well for both results true as well as false
   true--it returns me the resource/data requested by my URL
   false--it redirects me to the accessDenied page.

   If I pass values like /getGroupMembers.action?groupId=678342 for which no group exits in DB ,the method appropriately throws Exception as group fetched corresponding to groupId is null. But my web application simply redirects me to blank page. Is there any configuration missing in my URL security, so that if any exception thrown by the methods performing access checks, I can redirect to a common error page?

Comment: Why throw an exception? Why not simply return false, the exception breaks the proper flow. If you really must throw an exception throw an `AccessDeniedException` or a one of the exceptions extending from `AuthenticationException`.

Answer (score 1):

try throwing AccessDeniedException instead of Exception in your implementation of amIAMemberOfThisGroup.
ExceptionTranslationFilter calls accesDeniedHandler's handle method if AccessDeniedException is thrown

Comment: I think accessDeniedException wouldn't be appropriate as it would mean that group by that id might exist and we dont have access to it. Had I not checked (group==null), and proceeded with applying getters/setters on it, the method would have thrown nullpointer Exception. So I wan't a generic handler to all such unintended exceptions.

Comment: In this case (like Null pointer exception) when you want a handler for generic exception, then its not neccessary that exception is related to security. For such cases you can define a static error page in your web.xml. Spring security will handle only those exceptions that are related to Authentication/Authorisation

Comment: SO isn't there any other way in SPRING SECURITY to handle the exceptions and based on the exception type redirect to some pages?    Though this can be done in web.xml, I will surely appreciate the same setting in SPRING SECURITY CONFIGUARTION XML.